# Not able to update node js to V6.4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I installed node V6.4.0 for windows(x64). When I check "node --version" from console I am seeing "v0.12.0".

How to update node js to 6.4.0? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Check which `Node.exe` you're actually running.

Comment: @SLaks, Thanks. You are right. Until now I am checking on cmd.exe. When I tried node.js command prompt I see "v6.4.0". How to set this version globally? My System variable has path set to "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"

Comment: Use `where` to figure out what file you're running.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood. I mean When I run "node -v" from cmd prompt I should get v6.4.0. How can I fix trhis?

Comment: Run `where node` to find out what other copy of Node you're running.

Comment: @SLaks, Thanks. I see two versions of node when i run >where node                               C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe.  I will update path of  "v6.4.0" in my environment variables. Hope that makes my issue solved. Is that correct?

Comment: You should uninstall the 32-bit copy.

Comment: hmm Not sure how it got there. In my "uninstall program" i see nodejs installed version 6.4.0. can i uninstall this using npm command? or can i simply delete nodejs folder from C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe.?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Windows Control Panel.
2. Choose the “Programs and Features” option.
3. Click the “Uninstall a program” option.
4. Select Node.js, and click the Uninstall link.

Then reinstall Node from the NodeJS.org install package

Comment: That is very unlikely to help.